# UITabViewController with a UINavigationController as a tab

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

I have data being shared by two tabs of a `UITabBarController`. The first tab is in charge of generating and updating the array of data which is consumed by the second tab.

My original method of sharing the data between the tabs worked.

```
                      ------UIViewController
---UITabBarController
                      ------UIViewController
```

Using the above method, I accessed the array of data from the first tab as such:

```
let pointsViewController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.first as! ShowPointsViewController
tableHeaders = pointsViewController.tableHeaders
```

With ShowPointsViewController being the the first tab

**Here is my issue:**
When I embed my first `UIViewController` into a `UINavigationController` and then try to access my array of data using code below, I get a runtime error because the code after the `.first...` is returning as nil. I understand I am accessing this incorrectly, what is the correct way of achieving the same result?

```
 let pointsViewController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.first?.navigationController?.topViewController as! ShowPointsViewController
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well you created something like this:

```
                      ------UINavigationController    ------UIViewController
---UITabBarController
                      ------UINavigationController    ------UIViewController
```

You are getting nil as self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.first is already UINavigationController.

Use following code:

```
 let pointsViewController = (self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.first as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController as! ShowPointsViewController
```

Comment: Gahhhh perfect this worked. I thought Swift's type inference would have allowed me to avoid having to cast as a `UINavigationController`. Why did this not apply here out of curiosity?

Comment: self.tabBarController?.viewControllers contains Array of UIViewControllers. Not all of them have to be UINavigationController (like in your previous example) and because you need to get to topViewController property typical to UINavigationController you need casting.

Answer (score 0):

`self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.first?`is your `navigationController`, so you are calling `.navigationController` on the navigationcontroller, which returns `nil`.

To fix this, remove `.navigationController` from your call:

```
let pointsViewController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.first?.topViewController as! ShowPointsViewController
```